# Carr's colourful boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

does anyone know how (if possible) to produce a boxplot like the "Carr’s colourful boxplot" (i.e. above and below median different color; an exaple can be visualized in this pdf document(http://mason.gmu.edu/~dcarr/lib/v5n3.pdf)) in ggplot2 or in R (if not possible with ggplot2)?

I also posted that question on the ggplot2 google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/DYfUKoo-38g) with no luck

Thank you
Martin Lavoie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two calls of `stat_boxplot()` and then for first make `lower=` and `middle=` the same as `..middle..` (this will produce only upper part of boxplot) and for the second call make `upper=` and `ymax=` the same as `..middle..` (this will produce only lower part of boxplot). With `fill=`and `color=` you can get colors as you need.

```
ggplot(iris,aes(Species,Sepal.Length))+
  stat_boxplot(aes(lower=..middle..,ymin=..middle..),fill="red",color="red")+
  stat_boxplot(aes(upper=..middle..,ymax=..middle..),fill="blue",color="blue")
```

[image]